# Calculate average of data at different levels by year

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following Data :

[image: INPUT DATA]

I want to achieve a solution where, when I filter year, it returns me the average of Goodwill of that year and the previous year.

So for my year filter 2017: Average of Goodwill in 2017,2016

```
            year filter 2016: Average of Goodwill in 2016,2015

            .... and so on
```

The year is in General format (NOT Date format) ..

Expected OUTPUT Values:

[image: OUTPUT VALUES]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you have tried (or how familiar you are with Power BI/DAX), but you will most likely need to use a combination of [`DIVIDE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/divide-function-dax), [`CALCULATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax), and [`ALL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax). The `DIVIDE` function isn't super necessary, but it is a great habit to get into as it catches errors. Combining the `CALCULATE` and `ALL` will allow you to take the sum for the selected year and the prior year.

What I would do is this:

```
Goodwill - 2yr Avg = 
VAR MaxSelectedYear = MAX([Year])
VAR PriorYear = MaxSelectedYear - 1
VAR MinYearInData = MINX(ALL(Data), [Year])
RETURN
    DIVIDE(
        CALCULATE(SUM([Goodwill]), FILTER(ALL(Data[Year]), [Year] = MaxSelectedYear))
        +
        CALCULATE(SUM([Goodwill]), FILTER(ALL(Data[Year]), [Year] = PriorYear))
        ,
        IF(PriorYear < MinYearInData, 1, 2),
        BLANK()
    )
```

The `IF` statement at the end will catch when you are looking at the first year, so that the sum is only divided by 1 instead of 2. The sum will only be 1 year of data since when you filter the Data table to the prior year, there will be no data.

Comment: Thanks, Joe, that worked. 

I made a small edit instead of ALL I used ALLEXCEPT and fixed the company column to arrive at the exact output.

FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(Data,Data[Company]), [Year] = MaxSelectedYear)
FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(Data,Data[Company]), [Year] = PriorYear)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
 My Average = 
IF(HASONEVALUE(Data[Year]);
    DIVIDE(
        CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Goodwill]);FILTER(ALL(Data[Year]);Data[Year]>=SELECTEDVALUE(Data[Year])-1 && Data[Year]<=SELECTEDVALUE(Data[Year])))
        ;2);
    BLANK()
)
```

**HASONEVALUE**, just to identify if my current scope only has 1 year selected for the calculation to be applied.
Than getting the value for the current year and previous year with **FILTER** and **SELECTEDVALUE**

I am hardcoding the division by two, but you can adjust it depending on your dataset and purpose.